# Songs dont finish playing

Tags: itunes

Some of my songs do not finish playing on my iphone. I have tried enabling itunes match and syncing on the computer. Songs will shut off or stop with like 35 seconds remaining in the song. Help?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me in the past. Seems like the download from iCloud may have been corrupted; try deleting it from your iPhone, and downloading/syncing again.